# Cannot Sign In to OpenShift using Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, openshift

I am currently learning OpenShift and would like to experiment with a few examples. I have created an OpenShift account (using my github account as a login) and was able to create a new project and deploy an application online. Note that I'm using OpenShift Online (Developer Preview) which I think is OpenShift 3.

Now, I'd like to import that OpenShift project into Eclipse IDE. However, I cannot sign in to connect to the online server.

I tried both the versions 2 and 3 of the OpenShift server unsuccessfully. Attached is a screenshot of the error I'm getting

[image]

As shown on the screenshot, I can get a token when clicking the retrieve link (which does take me to the OpenShift site, with a token generated. This shows that eclipse does connect to https//console.preview.openshift.com).

I've also tried authentication with both username and password, leading to the same outcome.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try with https://api.preview.openshift.com as REST API endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for helping. In fact, I must have some problems with my developer console preview, as I'm able to successfully sign in using other (Openshift )URLs.

Comment: When I sign in subsequently to Openshift online using my GitHub credentials, I get the following message:

Comment: You do not have access to the Developer Preview. If you have already requested access you will receive an email when you are approved. It's only been less than 3 days since I signed up for a free account

Comment: The developer preview for OpenShift 3  is independent of the older OpenShift 2. You do need to separately request access for the developer preview. Accounts are time limited to 30 days and new people are added as old ones are cycled out and resources are available. You may not get an immediate response to registration. Do still make sure you check your spam box in case a reply came to there indicating your account is ready.

Comment: As you've been able to log in before, using your GitHub account, the trouble you were facing 17 hours ago could have been caused by [this recent incident](https://status.preview.openshift.com/incidents/m3rnkrwdy1qp).

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you are using the free version. You need to use you console address in 'Server:' that you get after clicking the **'Open Web Console'** button that you get after logging in to openshift. 
This url should be something like this: "https://console.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com/console/catalog". You may use just "https://console.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com". And then click 'Next', it should work.